# How can I get a borderless child window to re-scale to current screen in multi-monitor setup?

Tags: windows, qt, qml

My app has a main window which creates and opens an instance of a subclass of a QML `Window {}` using `createObject()`. This window has its `flags:` set to be a borderless window (I've added code so that it can be grabbed and dragged around).

When I attach a monitor to my laptop and set its font scale factor to 125% (or 150%), when I drag my main window over to the second monitor, you can see it suddenly "snap" to the larger size when it reaches the halfway point. Likewise, when I drag it back to my laptop screen it again "snaps" to the smaller size when I get halfway over (this behavior is what I want, so no problems here).

My problem is that when I drag my created borderless window over into the monitor, it keeps the original 100% scale factor and does not "snap" to a larger size. If I drag my main window over to the monitor, it gets larger but the borderless window remains at the smaller scale; only when I grab the borderless window and move it slightly does it suddenly "snap" to the larger scale size. The same thing happens in reverse - if I then drag the borderless window back onto the laptop, it remains at the larger size until I drag the main window back over and then move the borderless window slightly (at which point it suddenly "snaps" to the smaller size).

So it appears that this created `Window` uses the scale factor of the screen that the <del>parent window</del> window that created it is currently in, even if it is in a different screen itself.

Is this happening because the `Window` is borderless? (I'm about to test this but my build process is incredibly slow)  Or is there any way to set this borderless `Window` up so that it detects that it is crossing into a new screen and re-scales itself (in the same way that my main window does)?

**Update:** I just ran a test giving my `Window` a native titlebar, and with a titlebar the window instantly adopts ("snaps to") the scale factor of whichever screen it happens to be in, just like my main window (and independent of the main window's scale factor).

So is there any way to duplicate this auto-scaling window behavior with a borderless window? Some flag I need to call, or some method(s) I need to call to get the OS to rescale the window?

**Update 2:** I tried out Felix's `SetWindowPos` solution. It does move the window, but this does not fix the scaling problem - the behavior of the frameless window is the same and it still does not correctly pick up the scaling factor of the screen it is in.

I am running a test using `MoveWindow` instead of `SetWindowPos` to see if that affects anything [**edit:** `MoveWindow` does not work, either - same problem]. Then I'm going to try `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` along with NoBugz' suggestion of the WM_DPICHANGED message.

Any other suggestions are welcome.

**Update 3:** I just created a quick C# app (winforms) to see if the same problem occurs with that, and it doesn't - when a borderless form in the C# app is dragged over into the other monitor, it immediately picks up the scale factor change. So it appears this is a Qt problem.

**Update 4:** See my answer below for a working solution to this problem (if a bit of a hack).

Comment: This seems worthy of a bug report.

Comment: @GrecKo I don't know that it's a bug, though, exactly. The docs for the FramelessWindowHint say: "Produces a borderless window. The user cannot move or resize a borderless window via the window system." I suspect that moving the window "via the window system" (i.e. with a normal titlebar) is what lets the OS detect that the window has moved to a new monitor and it should be  re-scaled.

Comment: It may well be the cause of this behavior yes, but I feel this is not the expected/wanted behavior. Maybe a workaround can be found, if not a note mentionning this fact should be added to the `FramelessWindowHint` docs.

Comment: @GrecKo have you ever encountered a code sample that shows how to make the windows SetWindowPos API call from Qt?

Comment: No, I haven't (:

Comment: Beware that the post is misleading, it can't be a child window since you can't move child out of its parent.  Perhaps an owned window, always on top of its owner and minimizes as well when you minimize the owner.   You *might* be able to leverage the WM_DPICHANGED message, that's how Qt knows that it needs to rescale.  There have been lots of changes in recent Win10 versions to make this work better, you'd need dpiAware=True/PMv2 in the manifest to take advantage of it.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't say it was a child window, and by "parent window" I meant "window that created this other window". I've edited my post to avoid any confusion about a literal parent/child form relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a relatively simple way to fix this problem. Since a frameless window in Qt gets its scaling factor from the window that created it, the trick is to create another window (that has a titlebar but is not visible to the user) and create the frameless window there, and then add code to the frameless window to keep the hidden window positioned underneath it as the user drags it. When the frameless window is dragged into another screen, the hidden window goes with it, picks up the new scale factor (since it has a titlebar) and then the frameless window immediately gets the new screen's scale factor as well.

Here is sample solution code:

```
// HiddenWindow.qml
Window {
    id: hiddenWindow

    // note: just making window visible: false does not work. 
    opacity: 0
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.Tool | Qt.WindowTitleHint | Qt.WindowTransparentForInput | 
           Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint // Qt.Tool keeps this window out of the 
                 // taskbar

    function createVisibleWindow() {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("VisibleWindow.qml")
        if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
            var win = component.createObject(hiddenWindow)
            return win
        }
    }
}

// VisibleWindow.qml
Window {
    id: visibleWindow
    property var creatorWindow: undefined

    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    onXChanged: {
        creatorWindow.x = x
    }
    onYChanged: {
        creatorWindow.y = y
    }
    onWidthChanged: {
        creatorWindow.width = width
    }
    onHeightChanged: {
        creatorWindow.height = height
    }
}
```

And then to use these classes from your main window QML:

```
property var hiddenWindow: undefined
property var visibleWindow: undefined

Component.onCompleted: {

    var component = Qt.createComponent("HiddenWindow.qml")
    if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
        hiddenWindow = component.createObject(null)
    }
    visibleWindow = hiddenWindow.createVisibleWindow()
    visibleWindow.creatorWindow = hiddenWindow

    visibleWindow.show()

}
```

Answer (score 6):

So as far as I understand, your current goal is to move the window via the WIN-API.
You will have to do so via C++. The approach would be:

1. Pass the QML Window to a C++-Method exposed to QML as a [`QQuickWindow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html) (The QML window instanciates that type, as seen in the documentation)
2. Use [`QWindow::winId`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#winId) to get the native HWND
3. Call the [`SetWindowPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) WIN-API method to move it

Code sample (C++-part):

```
// the method
void moveWindow(QQuickWindow *window, int x, int y) {
    HWND handle = (HWND)window->winId();
    Q_ASSERT(handle);
    ::SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOP,
                   x, y, 0, 0,
                   SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
}

// assuming "moveWindow" is a member of "MyClass"
qmlEngine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("mover", new MyClass(qmlEngine));
```

Code sample (QML-part):

```
// call this method as soon as the drag has finished, with the new positions
mover.moveWindow(idOfWindow, xPos, yPos);
```

**Note:** I would recommend you try out calling this only after the drag was finished (and move the window as you do right now until then). If that works, you can try out what happens if you call this during the drag instead of changing the x/y of the window.

Comment: Well, `SetWindowPos` worked as far as moving the frameless window is concerned, but it doesn't fix the scaling problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Hm. Well, I guess you will have to dive deeper into the WIN-API and find out how to correctly move and rescale a window using it.

Comment: This method looks likely: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setdialogdpichangebehavior But I can't find any code samples that show how to actually call this method. In particular I don't understand the `mask` and `values` params and why they both take `DIALOG_DPI_CHANGE_BEHAVIORS` enums.

Comment: I am not familiar with these either - simply try them out and see what happens. You could also try to have a look at the fix that Qt did for this (as stated in your post). That might help you to find the correct things you need to do

Comment: Well, my solution turned out to be totally different from any of this. Thanks for your help anyway, though, I learned quite a bit of useful stuff from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize window when window move to other screen

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
    onPressed: {
        movePos = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)
        isDoubleClicked = false
        lastWindowWidth = mainWindow.width
        lastWindowHeight = mainWindow.height
    }
    onPositionChanged: {
        if (!isDoubleClicked) {
            const delta = Qt.point(mouse.x - movePos.x, mouse.y - movePos.y)
            if (mainWindow.visibility !== Window.Maximized) {
                mainWindow.x = mainWindow.x + delta.x
                mainWindow.y = mainWindow.y + delta.y
                mainWindow.width = lastWindowWidth
                mainWindow.height = lastWindowHeight
            }
        }
    }
}
```