# MoveWindow does not scale the window when moving to a different screen

Tags: c++, winapi, scaling, multiple-monitors, movewindow

I have a Windows application with floating windows. I am running it on a multi-monitor setup (FHD, 4K). The application is marked as system-aware, so we pick the current DPI value for the primary monitor and scale according to that. After that, the OS bitmap-scales it. The application is running on Windows 10.

Now, when one of the floating windows is dragged to another monitor, the OS bitmap-scales it automatically, and it all works fine.

The problem is that we have some windows without a title bar, and we have code to move those windows by dragging from the client area of the window. When the mouse is released, we call the `MoveWindow()` API to move the window to the target location. This works fine on a single monitor, but when we drop the window on a different monitor, it does not bitmap-scale, it seems to lose its drop location. The OS only seems to bitmap-scale when we drag a window by its title bar and not when it is moved programmatically.

Any ideas on how this automatic scaling can be achieved when moving a window programmatically?

Comment: Why don't you handle `WM_NCHITTEST` on windows that don't have a titlebar, returning `HTCAPTION`, and have the system deal with everything else?

Comment: These floating windows are actually custom made dockable toolbars created using title-less windows. The mouse movement is tracked to see if it will dock at the current location. Its all existing old code and I am trying to figure out why manual dragging scales the window but MoveWindow does not.

Comment: Even with handling `WM_NCHITTEST` the window does not scale. The only improvement I see is that it does not oddly jump to a different location. I had previously tried simulating a `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` on a `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and it simulated the drag but the window still didn't scale when moved to another screen

Comment: Another way to let the OS drag a title-less window for you is to send the window a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message with the undocumented but well-known `SC_DRAGMOVE` (0xF012) command.

Comment: Ensure you [asked for PMv2](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/04/04/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-desktop-applications-windows-10-creators-update/).

Comment: I suggest you could try to use [SetWindowPos function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to move it. You could refer to the thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757438/how-can-i-get-a-borderless-child-window-to-re-scale-to-current-screen-in-multi-m

Comment: I tried SC_DRAGMOVE and SetWindowPos and none worked for me. It would move the window but wouldn't scale it. I've posted an answer on how I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it depends on how the window is created. I fixed it by creating the window using `WS_CAPTION` style and then removing that style later. I am not sure what is does internally but it now scales correctly when it is moved to another screen either through mouse-drag or by using an API such as `MoveWindow`.

```
::CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW,...,..., WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION,...);
::SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, ::GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_CAPTION);
```