# Disabling minimize feature in qml

Tags: python-3.x, qml, conky, rainmeter

Is there a way prevent Qt windows from ever minimizing?

I'm trying to build something like [conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky) (Linux) or [rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net) (Windows) with pyside2 and qml (Qt). The effect I'm looking for is a borderless window that stays just above the wallpaper but behind everything else. Every method I've tried so far hides the window when `Super`+`D` is pressed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I intercept and cancel the minimizing of a Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51509507/how-can-i-intercept-and-cancel-the-minimizing-of-a-window)

Comment: no unfortunately.

Comment: That answer would work fantastically for framed windows but what I'm making is a frameless window.

Comment: if your window should be always on top `flag: Qt.BypassWindowManagerHint` works fine.